# Wordpress REST API search products

Tags: json, wordpress, woocommerce

Hope that you can help me.

I have a website that runs wooccommerce. I am using the woocommerce rest api. Now on another website what I want to do is create a simple search field where I type something and the search form needs to search through the woocommerce website and return results.

Is there a way I can achieve that ?

Answer (score 11):

Try this:

```
/wp-json/wc/v2/products?search={{product_name}}
```

Works for me.

Answer (score 2):

**This works for me in 2021:**

`/wp-json/wc/v3/products?search={{productName}}`

**productName** - refers to the input that you enter in the Search box

Answer (score 1):

If you use a wc-api-php (PHP library), please follow like this :

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use Automattic\WooCommerce\Client;

$woocommerce = new Client(
    'http://mydomain', // Your store URL
    'ck_****', // Your consumer key
    'cs_****', // Your consumer secret
    [
        'wp_api' => true, // Enable the WP REST API integration
        'version' => 'wc/v3' // WooCommerce WP REST API version
    ]
);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($woocommerce->get('products', ['search' => 'key word']));
echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think no.
The New Version of WooCommerce API (v2) is supports id based calls.
so instead you can get a list of abstract product details in your 2nd website and call back via product id.

Answer (score 0):

/wp-json/wc/v2/products?search={{product_name}}

Is this function working if you are looking a exact product?

If you have a product like MR2050 and another with MR2050K, the result is not as you may expected, cause API rest will return 2 products, not just ONE?

Comment: This was posted as asnwer, but I think it is not the solution to the question, possibly it should be a comment.
Please do not ask questions in the answer and take the tour and read How to Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).